# Nested dictionary to class by type

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection

I'm trying to convert a nested Dictionary to nested class base on its type.
For example. I have this dictionary:

```
{
    "owner": {
        "name": {
            "first": "Linh",
            "last": "Nguyen"
        },
        "age": "Nguyen"
    },
    "power": {
        "index": "1",
        "range": "5"
    }
}
```

And I have this nested class :

```
    public class AccountRegistrationViewModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Account owner.
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        public Owner Owner { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// User age.
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        public int Age { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Account photo.
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        public List<HttpFile> Photos { get; set; }
    }

    public class Owner
    {
        public Name Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Name
    {
        public string First { get; set; }

        public string Last { get; set; }
    }
```

And I have this function:

```
T Convert<T>(IDictionary<string, object> input, Type classType)
{
    // Do something.
    return T;
}
```

In javascript, it is very easy to do this task, but currently, I don't know how to achieve this task by using C#.

Can someone help me please?

Thank you,

Comment: So your dictionary is what exactly? Is that just the primitive values displayed as json for some reason? Also `"age": "Nguyen"` ? It would be better if you created an MCVE, a method where you create the dictionary with values as you would receive it. Post that in the question.

Comment: Also why use generics here if you know what it is you want to convert to? Using generics serves no purpose.

Comment: I'm trying to build a media formatter for web api.

Comment: That is not what I asked about...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who wants to convert nested dictionary to a class.

Actually, my question is for making a new multipart/form-data formatter for Web API 2. I've tried some formatters made for Web API 2 but it failed to deal with nested class when a file is uploaded.

https://gist.github.com/Danielku15/bfc568a19b9e58fd9e80
[How create a MultipartFormFormatter for ASP.NET 4.5 Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17924655/how-create-a-multipartformformatter-for-asp-net-4-5-web-api)

[Here](http://pastebin.com/nYZ4vFjU) is my alternative multipart/form-data formatter.

My implementation may not be the best, but at least we can improve it later.
Thanks to the miracle comes from Reflection.